# How to pass Managed Identity Object ID to KeyVault template in Azure Blueprints

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, objectid, azure-managed-identity, infrastructure-as-code

So, I am trying to spin up a `Managed Identity` and a `KeyVault` using `Blueprints`. I have an individually working template for each. My endgoal is to spin up both resources along with a few more together in the same blueprint. The issue I'm having is that I need to pass my Managed Identity's object ID to the KeyVault template during deployment. I have the blueprint setup to deploy the managed identity resource group, then the managed identity, followed by the keyvault group and keyvault.

The deployment is working till the KV resource group and then failing during deployment of keyvault. Does anyone have any insight on how to do this?

Below are 2 pics that show the layout of the blueprint and also the section of the keyvault template where the object Id is needed.

**Azure Blueprint Layout:**
[image: Azure Blueprint Layout]

**KeyVault Template where access policy to managed Identity is located:**
[image: KeyVault Template where access policy to managed Identity is located]

**Error Pic:**
[image: Error Pic]

**Pic of the error on the next page after I click view deployment details:**
[image: Pic of the error on the next page after i click view deployment details]

Comment: Could you please post the failing message? So, we can take a look and try to help you.

Comment: I added them above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description and screenshot, you want to add the UserAssigned Managed Identity to your keyvault along with the creation of it, and the keyvault and Managed Identity are in *different* resource groups.

If so, the `accessPolicies` should be below, it works fine on my side.

```
"accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                        "objectId": "[reference(ResourceId(parameters('managedIdentityRG'), 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('managedIdentityName')),'2018-11-30','Full').properties.principalId]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get"
                            ],
                            "certificates": []
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

---

My complete template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vaults_joykeyvault12_name": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "managedIdentityName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "managedIdentityRG":{
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
            "name": "[parameters('vaults_joykeyvault12_name')]",
            "location": "eastus",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "family": "A",
                    "name": "Standard"
                },
                "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                        "objectId": "[reference(ResourceId(parameters('managedIdentityRG'), 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', parameters('managedIdentityName')),'2018-11-30','Full').properties.principalId]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get"
                            ],
                            "certificates": []
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "enabledForDeployment": false,
                "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
                "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false,
                "enableSoftDelete": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Perfect Solution. I didnt have to modify anything to make it work. Just make sure that all the parameter values line up.